# How to restrict buffering in video steaming in android

Tags: android, video-streaming

I want to restrict buffering after pausing a video in android. When I pause the video player, the video stops but buffering does not. It continues to consume data. I want to stop data to be consumed. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With a standard mp4/webm, you can’t. It’s totally up the the browser. If you use fragmented mp4 and feed the buffer via MSE and Ajax, you can do whatever you want. But it’s a thousand time more work on your part.

Comment: I want to restrict buffering from my android app. I am using VideoView of ExoMedia.

Answer (score -1):

You can't skip buffering it depends on the network